# how to create a reusable javascript web-app from my HTML CSS and JS files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web-applications

i have a working HTML file with CSS and JS files i want to create a web app with this.

i don't have any experience or idea how to create a webapp from what i have.

my code dosen't need any interaction with the server.

i have found this guide from [this site](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/)

```
    (function() {

// Localize jQuery variable
var jQuery;

/******** Load jQuery if not present *********/
if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '1.4.2') {
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src",
        "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");
    if (script_tag.readyState) {
      script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // For old versions of IE
          if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
              scriptLoadHandler();
          }
      };
    } else {
      script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
    }
    // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
} else {
    // The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
    jQuery = window.jQuery;
    main();
}

/******** Called once jQuery has loaded ******/
function scriptLoadHandler() {
    // Restore $ and window.jQuery to their previous values and store the
    // new jQuery in our local jQuery variable
    jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
    // Call our main function
    main(); 
}

/******** Our main function ********/
function main() { 
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
        /******* Load CSS *******/
        var css_link = $("<link>", { 
            rel: "stylesheet", 
            type: "text/css", 
            href: "style.css" 
        });
        css_link.appendTo('head');          

        /******* Load HTML *******/
        var jsonp_url = "http://al.smeuh.org/cgi-bin/webwidget_tutorial.py?callback=?";
        $.getJSON(jsonp_url, function(data) {
          $('#example-widget-container').html("This data comes from another server: " + data.html);
        });
    });
}

})(); // We call our anonymous function immediately
```

1.) i understood till loading CSS but i did not get what the code is doing for loading a HTML file.

2.) is it possible to do a webapp with what i have and how..?

3.) i know css html js jq.......... is it important to know ajax or anything else for creating a web app.

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but maybe if I try to describe what this script is doing, it will help you?

Basically, this script is (somewhat clumsily IMO) first loading jQuery, and then loading a stylesheet `style.css` and finally retrieving data from `http://al.smeuh.org/cgi-bin/webwidget_tutorial.py?callback=?`.  It assumes that you have a document element with the id `"example-widget-container"`, which is where it will inject the html received from the JSON call.

If you clarify what exactly you're asking, then maybe I or someone else can help you some more.

Comment: thnx bro for ur reply, actually im concerned about including my html file in the above code for loading. i don't know anything about JSON call. if there is any other way for creating widget with what i have( .html, .css, .js ) please guide me. thanks.

Comment: /******* Load HTML *******/
        var jsonp_url = "http://al.smeuh.org/cgi-bin/webwidget_tutorial.py?callback=?";
        $.getJSON(jsonp_url, function(data) {
          $('#example-widget-container').html("This data comes from another server: " + data.html);
        });

its written "this data comes from another server but i don't want it from server.... i have .html file.... how to load that html file..?